# Error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Error** inflating class fragment

---

I am trying to add *fragment in activity* at runtime dynamically. 
After running the app crashes.
***File names are***
There is a main activity(MainActivity.java), its xml(activity_main.xml)

A fragment (MainFragment.java), its xml (fragment_main.xml)

***Following is Code for app***.

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.vikashyadav.myquiz.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.vikashyadav.myquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_holder,new MainFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }


}
```

i am not able to find why this crashes.

Comment: put all your stacktrace here.

Comment: shouldn't fragment have a name or class attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove fragment layout by other like FrameLayout..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.vikashyadav.myquiz.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addFragment(R.id.fragment_holder,new MainFragment(), "MainFragment");
    }

    protected void addFragment(@IdRes int containerViewId, @NonNull Fragment fragment,@NonNull String fragmentTag) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag)
                .disallowAddToBackStack()
                .commit();
    }

}
```